# Nonempty open subset of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ spans $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

### Every proper nonempty open subset in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ spans $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

How do I proceed to prove this?

**Edit:**(As suggested by @dan_fulea)

Every open set contains an open ball so if I am able to show that the above statement is true for any open ball centered at some point then we are done.

If I consider the set $B=\{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}): ||A-0||<1\}$

$B$ contains $\mathcal{E}_{ij} \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $e_{ij}=\frac12$ ($ij^{th}$ entry). Now the set $\{\mathcal{E}_{ij}:1\le i,j\le n\}$ is linearly independent and generates $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Since $B$ contains all the matrices $\mathcal{E}_{ij}$, we get $B$ generates $M_n{(\mathbb{R})}$. Hence any open set containing $B$ generates $M_n{(\mathbb{R})}$.

---

So the question now is reduced to finding an answer for open balls which are not centered at $0$.

---

### **Corollary:**

### Every proper subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is nowhere dense in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

As every proper subspace is closed, it cannot contain any open subset of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. As it would generate $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, contradicting the subspace being closed.

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve the problem, it is the way it works on this site. (For instance, given an open subset $U$, reduce successively the problem to $U$ is a ball, $U$ is a ball centered in $0$, $U$ is the unit ball for some matrix norm...)

Comment: I am clueless at the moment

Comment: Above, there are clear hints to solve the problem. What is unclear in the hints? You **must** give something. For instance, show what you can do for the trivial case $n=1$. If you cannot do anything in this case, then the problem is not for your level. This is not a site delivering solutions for copy+pasted problems. Instead, it is a site for a community, based on communication, from a didactical point of view you must show some starting steps, very often a solution will be given exactly with this start - or showing why the start was not a good start.

Comment: @dan_fulea: I am sorry. I have added my efforts although I have borrowed them from your comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly many approaches. Here's one. The idea is to start at some point of the open set and travel towards some arbitrary destination matrix by linear interpolation. You stay inside the open set for at least a little bit. But spans that contain line segments contain the full line, so you can get to the destination that way.

More formally, let $U \subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be open and non-empty. Pick $U_0 \in U$ and $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Consider $tU_0 + (1-t)A$. Since $U$ is open, for sufficiently small $t_0>0$ we have $B := t_0U_0 + (1-t_0)A \in U$. But then
$$A = \frac{1}{1-t_0}(t_0 U_0 + (1-t_0)A) - \frac{t_0}{1-t_0} U_0 = \frac{1}{1-t_0} B - \frac{t_0}{1-t_0} U_0 \in \mathrm{span}(U).$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n^2},$ it suffices to prove this for $\mathbb R^{m}=\mathbb R^{n^2}.$ As pointed out in the comments, we may assume that our open set is a ball containing the origin, $B_{2r}(0).$ (To prove this, note that every open set contains a ball, and that translation is a homeomorphism). The claim now follows as soon as we note that $\{r\vec e_i\}_{i=1}^m\subseteq B_{2r}(0)$ is a linearly independent set of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb R^m$ and so basic linear algebra tells us that every vector $\vec v\in \mathbb R^m$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $\{r\vec e_i\}_{i=1}^m.$

Comment: Does homeomorphism between two vector spaces carries basis of one vector space into that of the other?

Comment: Yes, it does, It is an isomorphism but more importantly, it is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse.

Comment: Translation does not preserve linear combinations, so a homeomorphism between two vector spaces definitely does not in general carry a basis to a basis. One at least needs the origin to be fixed, for instance. A linear bijection between finite-dimensional real vector spaces works fine, of course. It is strange to me to mention linear independence of the standard basis vectors and leverage that to argue that they form a spanning set, since they of course obviously span.

Comment: I was referring to the homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ and $M_n(\mathbb R)$. Of course, the only property you need as far as translations go, is that they send opens to opens. The fact that the ball $B$ contains $m$ linearly independent vectors means simply that they span the vector space, and this shows that elements of $B$ generate it, which is what the OP wanted to show, Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm saying it would have been better to write, "...is a spanning set of $m$ vectors". The proof that $\{r\vec{e}_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is linearly independent is just as easy as showing that it's spanning. The proof that a linearly independent subset of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is spanning is not trivial and uses the Rank-Nullity Theorem. So your current arrangement implicitly uses an unnecessary trek through theory.

Comment: What? The $\vec e_i$ are the canonical basis vectors. The proof that they span is trivial.